# PHP - File_get_contents doesn't detect CURL responce

Tags: php, json, curl, file-get-contents

I've my script here:

```
<?php

$auth_token = "privateprivateprivate";
$curl = curl_init("https://api-sandbox.coingate.com/v2/orders/");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Token " .$auth_token;




$output = curl_exec($curl);
$output_json = file_get_contents($output);
$output_array = json_decode($output_json);

$message = $output_array["message"];
$reason  = $output_array["reason"];

echo $message;
echo $reason;
?>
```

What i'm trying to do is to make a call to "https://api-sandbox.coingate.com/v2/orders/" and to fetch info's using `file_get_contents()` function of PHP.

The results of that file is JSON so I do a basic decode but when I run the php scripts, it says:
 *file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in ...*

This is my first attempt at working with curl, can I get some help please?

Thanks!

Comment: `curl_exec` delivers the response directly to the browser and it just returns if it was successful or not: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: Oh alright thanks, and how can I grab contents of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the requested data and save it to a variable, you can use the [`curl_setopt`](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php) function with the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option:

```
<?php

$auth_token = "privateprivateprivate";
$headers = [
    "Authorization: Token " .$auth_token,
];

$curl = curl_init("https://api-sandbox.coingate.com/v2/orders/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$output = curl_exec($curl);
$output_array = json_decode($output);

var_dump($output, $output_array);
```

To read more you can take a look into the PHP cURL documentation: http://de.php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php